# Proof verification that if $A$ is a subset in a metric space $(X,d)$ then $cl A = X\setminus[int (X\setminus A)]$

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$
This is an exercise from Conway's A Course in Point Set Topology. I constantly use the following Proposition 1.1.13 (P1.1.13): Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y\subseteq X$, then

a) $x\in \int\,Y \Longleftrightarrow \exists r>0[B(x;r)\subseteq Y]$
b) $x\in \cl\,Y \Longleftrightarrow \forall r>0[B(x;r)\cap Y \ne\varnothing]$

The Exercise 1.7 which is proving Proposition 1.1.15(c-1): Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq X$. Then $\cl A = X\setminus[\int (X\setminus A)]$.

Proof. Let $x\in \cl A$, by P1.1.13(b) it means that $\forall r>0[B(x;r)\cap A\ne \varnothing]$. Suppose $x\in \int (X\setminus A)$, hence by P1.1.13(a) we can choose an $r_0>0$ such that the open ball $B(x;r_0)\subseteq X\setminus A$, which contradicts the assumption that $\forall r>0[B(x;r)\cap A\ne \varnothing]$, thus $x\notin \int(X\setminus A)$. Also, from $\forall r>0[B(x;r)\cap A\ne \varnothing]$ we can conclude that $x\in A\subseteq X$, therefore $x\in X\setminus \int(X\setminus A)$. As $x$ was arbitrary, $\cl A \subseteq  X\setminus int(X\setminus A)$.

Now let $x\in X\setminus[\int(X\setminus A)]$, and let $F\subseteq X$ be any closed set such that $A\subseteq F$. Suppose $x \notin F$, then $x\notin \cl A$, and $x\in X\setminus F$, so since $F$ is closed there is an $r_{F}>0$ such that the $B(x;r_F)\subseteq X\setminus F$. Given that $x\notin \int(X\setminus A)$, by P1.1.13 it implies that $\forall r>0 [B(x;r)\nsubseteq X\setminus A]$, thus $B(x;r_F)\nsubseteq X\setminus A$, which contradicts that $A\subseteq F$ and $B(x;r_r)\subseteq X\setminus F$, therefore $x\in \cl A$. Since $F$ was arbitrary then $x\in \cl A$, and as $x$ was arbitrary $X\setminus[\int(X\setminus A)]\subseteq \cl A$.

We can conclude that $X\setminus[\int(X\setminus A)]=\cl A$. $\square$

Is this proof right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some typos, one essential flaw, and non-necessary use of $F$.
I have suggested edition of question fixing the typos.

In the latter part of the first paragraph, you cannot conclude $x\in A$ from $x\in clA$ because apparently $clA$ can be larger than $A$.

The second paragraph seems correct, but you do not need to use $F$. You can just assume $x \notin clA$ instead of $x\notin F$, to obtain $r_F$ by 1.1.13b.

Note that the discussion in the second paragraph has shown that assuming both $x \notin clA$ and $x \notin int(X\setminus A)$ implies contradiction. This is sufficient for replacing your flaw in the latter part of the first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the edits! I will be checking your feedback.

Comment: You're right it does not necessarily follow that $x\in A$ from $x\in cl A$. Thus for showing that $x\in X$, can I suppose $x\notin X$, which is a contradiction with the fact that $x\in cl A$, since $cl A$ must be in $X$, then $x\in X$?